Difference between deleting and not writing a constructor
The following code snippet
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntegerContainer {
public:
    IntegerContainer()
    {
        std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
    }
    IntegerContainer(int first, int second) : m_data{first, second}
    {
        std::cout << "two ints" << std::endl;
    }
    IntegerContainer(std::initializer_list<int> list) :  m_data{list}
    {
        std::cout << "ini-list" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};

int main () {
    IntegerContainer container2{ };
    IntegerContainer container3(1, 2);
    IntegerContainer container4{1, 2};
    return 0;
}

Leads to the following output:
default
two ints
ini-list

So container2 is constructed with the default constructor, and not with the initializer list. We can force container2 to be constructed with the initializer list by removing our default definition from the class:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntegerContainer {
public:
    IntegerContainer(int first, int second) : m_data{first, second}
    {
        std::cout << "two ints" << std::endl;
    }
    IntegerContainer(std::initializer_list<int> list) :  m_data{list}
    {
        std::cout << "ini-list" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};

int main () {
    IntegerContainer container2{ };
    IntegerContainer container3(1, 2);
    IntegerContainer container4{1, 2};
    return 0;
}

Leads to output:
ini-list
two ints
ini-list

But if we delete explicitly the default constructor:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntegerContainer {
public:
    IntegerContainer() = delete;
    IntegerContainer(int first, int second) : m_data{first, second}
    {
        std::cout << "two ints" << std::endl;
    }
    IntegerContainer(std::initializer_list<int> list) :  m_data{list}
    {
        std::cout << "ini-list" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};

int main () {
    IntegerContainer container2{ };
    IntegerContainer container3(1, 2);
    IntegerContainer container4{1, 2};
    return 0;
}

, we get a compilation error, e.g. the initializer list constructor cannot be called anymore:
ERROR!
/tmp/rUlkfwPSCr.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/tmp/rUlkfwPSCr.cpp:21:34: error: use of deleted function 'IntegerContainer::IntegerContainer()'
   21 |     IntegerContainer container2{ };
      |                                  ^
/tmp/rUlkfwPSCr.cpp:6:5: note: declared here
    6 |     IntegerContainer() = delete;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


=== Code Exited With Errors ===

I experimented on Programiz to produce those results.
So, according to cpp-reference :

If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type, the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.


If some user-declared constructors are present, the user may still force the automatic generation of a default constructor by the compiler that would be implicitly-declared otherwise with the keyword default.

I expect that in both the second case (no constructor without parameters written) and in the third case (explicitly deleted), the parmeter loss constructor does not exist. Why does the second compile, but the third one is not able to use the initliazier list constructor instead?

neither of the two quotes applies here. You did provide a user-declared constructor and you did not force automatic generation via default

the parmeter loss constructor does not exist. No. It does exist in the 3rd case. The compiler just selects it and then fails as it's marked as deleted.

Deleted function still take part in overload resolution. And if a deleted function is selected during this process, the program becomes ill-formed. See Ternary operator applied to class with conversion operator and delete constructor causes ambiguity

Also Why do C++11-deleted functions participate in overload resolution? and Is implicitly deleted default constructor same as Compiler not synthesizing the default constructor

The meaning of "= delete" here is "forbidden", not "non-existing", but the C++ committee is always very reluctant to add new keywords, so they chose to recycle "delete", which was already there.
